# Configuring ANTLR target output location with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, antlr3

I am new to ANTLR. I wanted to learning start by setting up a project so that lexers\parsers would be automatically generated by the build. So I downloaded antlr-dotnet-tool package, modified a project file to include antlr targets. I also installed some VS extension that add syntax highlighting and new item types for grammar files.

Now, generation seems to works, but it puts output files into obj/${Configuration} folder. And I don't really know what I am supposed to do with them there. Surely, you don't want me to manually copy them to proper locations (supposedly next to grammar files), do you?

It would be great if you could shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed my blog post, you will see that you need to do nothing else,

http://www.lextm.com/2012/07/how-to-use-antlr-on-net-part-v/ (note that at the beginning you will see links to the previous 4 parts)

At compile time the generated files are automatically linked to the output assembly, and the debugger is capable of loading them when you debug the program.

Comment: Yep, `obj/${Configuration}` is the correct folder, and everything including IntelliSense and debugging work automatically and seamlessly. No need to manually add the generated files to the project.

Comment: Well, since those files are not parts of the solution, you can't really use classes generated in them. At least, I couldn't - VS keeps complaining about these classes not having methods I want. What am I doing wrong? Perhaps, this is because of ReSharper.

Comment: Li, as a matter of fact, I did follow you blog post. :)

Comment: @EugeneStrizhok, the warnings and errors generated by ReSharper are quite annoying, and I suffer the same. However, Visual Studio works fine in most other cases, so I personally don't bother to find any other ways.

Comment: @EugeneStrizhok ReSharper does not support the extensible portion of MSBuild that ANTLR relies on. If you disable ReSharper, the IntelliSense support will be consistent and reliable (available to the whole project as soon as you save the grammar).